# Switch case in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

Is there a construct in Apache Camel (in Java DSL) similar to Java switch-case?

For example:

```
 from( incomingRoute )
    .choice()
    .when( simple( "${body.getType} == '" + TYPE.A.name() + "'" ) )
                .to( A_Endpoint )
    .when( simple( "${body.getType} == '" + TYPE.B.name() + "'" ) )
                .to( B_Endpoint )
    .when( simple( "${body.getType} == '" + TYPE.C.name() + "'" ) )
                .to( C_Endpoint )
   .otherwise()
                .to( errorEndpoint );
```

Can be translated into something else more similar to switch? I mean that I do not want to use simple predicates, only value of type of body element.
Or is my approach completely wrong? (That could reasonably be)

Comment: You could use Predicates, but it is not the same as the Java switch in the sense of assuming the equals() test. So, it is repetitive in its own way. Still, you might prefer it for readability in some cases: http://camel.apache.org/predicate.html

Comment: I completely agree with Darius, Camel `Predicate`s are generally the way to go in my opinion, your code is much more readable that way.

Answer (score 5):

I generally prefer using Java 8 lambdas in that particular scenario:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
  from( incomingRoute )
     .choice()
     .when( bodyTypeIs( TYPE.A ) )
                 .to( A_Endpoint )
     .when( bodyTypeIs(  TYPE.B ) )
                 .to( B_Endpoint )
     .when( bodyTypeIs(  TYPE.C ) )
                 .to( C_Endpoint )
     .otherwise()
                 .to( errorEndpoint );
}

private Predicate bodyTypeIs(TYPE type) {
  return e -> e.getIn().getBody(BodyType.class).getType() == type;
}
```

Also, using Camel's `Predicate`s with Java 8 allows for some awesome fluent API building, like adding your own type of functional `Predicate`:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ComposablePredicate extends Predicate, java.util.function.Predicate<Exchange> {

  @Override
  default boolean matches(Exchange exchange) {
    return test(exchange);
  }

  @Override
  default ComposablePredicate and(java.util.function.Predicate<? super Exchange> other) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(other);
    return (t) -> test(t) && other.test(t);
  }

  @Override
  default ComposablePredicate negate() {
    return (t) -> !test(t);
  }

  @Override
  default ComposablePredicate or(java.util.function.Predicate<? super Exchange> other) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(other);
    return (t) -> test(t) || other.test(t);
  }
}
```

Which allows you to write stuff like:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
  from( incomingRoute )
     .choice()
     .when( bodyTypeIs( TYPE.A ) .or ( bodyTypeIs( TYPE.A1 ) ) )
                 .to( A_Endpoint )
     .when( bodyTypeIs(  TYPE.B ).negate() )
                 .to( NOT_B_Endpoint )
     .when( bodyTypeIs(  TYPE.C ) .and ( bodyNameIs( "name" ) ) )
                 .to( C_Endpoint )
     .otherwise()
                 .to( errorEndpoint );
}

private ComposablePredicate bodyTypeIs(TYPE type) {
  return e -> bodyFrom(e).getType() == type;
}

private BodyType bodyFrom(Exchange e) {
  return e.getIn().getBody(BodyType.class);
}

private ComposablePredicate bodyNameIs(String name) {
  return e -> bodyFrom(e).getName().equals(name);
}
```